# Como registrar as notas de uma aluno usando o arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Necessito adicionar notas a determinados alunos(cada aluno possui varias notas e cada nota pertence a uma disciplina), porém como estou usando arrayList e possuo pouco conhecimento em java estou bem perdido na passagem de parametros e de como adicionar novos valores usando a função `registrarNota`.

Alguém poderia explicar o que devo fazer.

**PS(Não posso usar o Extends)**

Classe aluno:

```
package auladia24;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Aluno {
    private String nome;
    private String ra;
    private ArrayList<Nota> notas = new ArrayList(); // tipo da array e o nome da array

    public Aluno(String nome, String ra){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.ra = ra;
    }

    public String getNome (){
        return this.nome;
    }

    public String getRa(){
        return this.ra;
    }

    public ArrayList getNotas(){
        return this.notas;
    }

    public Nota registrarNota(double valor, Disciplina nomeDisciplina){

    }
}
```

Classe Nota:

```
package auladia24;

public class Nota {
    private double valor ;
    private Disciplina nomeDisciplica;

    public void  nota (double nota, Disciplina nomeDisciplina){
        this.valor = valor;    
        this.nomeDisciplica = nomeDisciplica;
    }

    public double getNota(){
        return this.valor;
    }

    public Disciplina getDisciplina(){
        return this.nomeDisciplica;
    }

}
```

Classe Disciplina:

```
package auladia24;

public class Disciplina {
    private String nome;

    public Disciplina (String nome){
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNome(){
        return this.nome;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pode utilizar outra forma para armazenar que não seja arraylist, como map?

Comment: Acredito que sim Diego

Comment: Se entendi bem, você quer armazenar notas e disciplina no aluno, de forma que possa relaciona a nota com a disciplina, é isso mesmo?

Comment: Isso exatamente isso

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você precisa utilizar o método `registrarNota` certo?
ele pede um double e um objeto Disciplina.

```
public Nota registrarNota(double valor, Disciplina nomeDisciplina)
{
    //primeiro checa se ja existe a nota
    for(Nota n : notas)
    { 
        if(n.getDisciplina().getNome().equals(objetoDisciplina.getNome()))
        {
            n.setNota(valor); 
            return n;
        }
    }
    Nota n = new Nota(valor, nomeDisciplina); //cria a nova nota
    notas.add(n); //adiciona ela no arraylist
    return n; //retorna a nota criada
}
```

É necessário adicionar o método `setNota` na classe `Nota`

```
public void setNota(double valor)
{
    this.valor = valor
}
```

Para chamar ela seria simplesmente `aluno.registrarNota(nota, objetoDisciplina);`

Comment: Pensei nisso também, mas tem um problema, pra atualizar uma nota, vai criar a mesma disciplna? Desta forma, uma mesma disciplina vai ficar com várias notas diferentes;

Comment: Talvez se você editar a resposta com alguma forma de verificar se a disciplina já existe, e apenas somar com o valor existente da nota, ficaria mais completo e sem o bug que eu citei.

Comment: Só precisa navegar dentro do seu arraylist `notas` procurando pelas notas que estão lá e verificar se alguma delas tem o nome da disciplina igual a nova que esta sendo adicionada.

Comment: Entendo, por isso sugeri que exemplificasse isso, o OP pode não saber deste detalhe, Alem de tornar sua resposta completa :)

Comment: Fui tentar reproduzir seu registrar nota no meu código porem quando vou passar os valores ele não aceita o tipo disciplina .
Agora fiquei em duvida de o meu construtor de Nota esta errado ou não

Comment: E realmente está meu construtor esta como void porem mesmo assim não consigo passar um parâmetro do tipo Disciplina